# Xlsxwriter conditional formatting after identifying rows with criteria

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, xlsxwriter

Good afternoon,

Im trying to change the conditional formatting with xlsxwriter.

Im able to do so using

```
percent_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%', 'align': 'center', 'border': 1})

worksheet.conditional_format('B1:J%d' % (number_rows),
                                        {"type": "formula",
                                        "criteria": '=INDIRECT("B"&ROW())="THISROW"',
                                        "format": percent_format 
                                        })
```

With this step I am able to assign any normal formatting, like bold, centered, etc, etc

But I need to apply conditional formatting over those rows like 3 color scale etc

I guess my question is how to create a set of cell ranges and then apply 3 color cond formatting over them.

Thank you!

EDIT 1:

Adding more info:

[image]

I want to apply 3 color cond formatting to the rows where THISROW is matched in the column

to C5:D5
C9:D9
C13:D13

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want a 3 color scale it's

```
worksheet7.conditional_format('I3:I14', {'type': '3_color_scale',
                                         'min_color': "#C5D9F1",
                                         'mid_color': "#8DB4E3",
                                         'max_color': "#538ED5"})
```

see examples here:
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_conditional_format.html

If you want a more complex output like your formula suggests then you are doing it properly but you need to repeat it numerous time (just like you would in Excel). If your formula doesn't work it's probably because the Excel formula doesn't work in Excel.

This

> '=INDIRECT("B"&ROW())="THISROWS"'

is two volatile functions where none is required. If you don't put $ in the adress of the cell the position is already relative. Hence if you start your area in B3 and end it in F15, for instance, if you write

> '=B3="THISROWS"'

then in B4, the B3 in your code will be replaced by B4. If you need it to move in the rows but not the columns write:

> '=$B3="THISROWS"'

Comment: Yes, the formula works to apply center, and borders, etc, to all the row where "THISROW" exists in the B column, but if I use the formula part to identify the 'range' i can not apply 3 color formatting over that range. I dont know if I'm explaining myself properly

Comment: I want to apply 3 color formatting for all the rows that "THISROW" in B to J columns exists

Comment: Ok so there are two things here:
1- =INDIRECT("B"&ROW())="THISROWS" might work but it contains two volatile formulas and it would not be recommanded since you can avoid the indirect and the row function. You can keep it if you want but I strongly suggest replacing it.

Comment: 2- For the 3 colors scales, it's a matter of if what you want is a gradient scale or not, 
a) The gradient conditional formatting only takes numeric values, not formulas, therefore you should identify the cells from the B column in python and apply conditional formatting to these cells only with the menthod aforementionned.

Comment: b) If however you want something like under 1.0 it's red, between 1.0 and 1.5 it's yellow and over 1.5 it green, then your conditional formatting needs to be from C1 to then bottom-right end of your data, and your formula needs to says:
`AND($B1="THISROWS",[your criteria])`
and you apply this conditional formatting for each color (it can be more than 3)
`AND($B1="THISROWS",C1<1)` #then it's red
`AND($B1="THISROWS",C1<=1.5,C1>=1)` #then it's yellow
`AND($B1="THISROWS",C1>=1.5)` #then it's green

Comment: that is the thing, the conditional formatting in xlsxwriter dont let me apply a formula to identify the range that i want to work with. I solved just doing a for loop in range of length of the dataframe, since the THISROW will be starting always at the 5th row and then add 4 for the next cond formatting, but that is not the way I wanted to do it :(

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way I intended to solve this, but using the xlxswriter package.. but here we go.

```
color_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'color': 'red'})
for i in range(len(df.index)/5):                                        
    worksheet.conditional_format('C{}:D{}'.format(5+4*i,5+4*i), {'type':     'cell',
                                        'criteria': '>=',
                                        'value':    1,
                                        'format':   color_format})
```

I'm ashamed to do it this way tho... now anything over 1 gets in red color...